# A word/phrase to describe this type of person

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe someone who thinks that their perspective is the only one, or is the universal fixed norm against which all other perspectives are judged. They think that if they have never personally experienced something, it thereby doesn't exist.

An example is an older heterosexual white man who thinks that oppression hasn't existed in 100 years.

I'm looking for a better descriptor than "ignorant" or "narrow-minded." Thank you.

Comment: I would tend to think 'reactionary', but I don't think that quite fits your description.

Comment: a lot of words with different nuances will work. Self-centered, immature, solipsistic, parochial, unworldly. Narrow-minded is pretty good. What's wrong with it?

Comment: "egocentric predicament" or "egocentric fallacy", the assumption that others think as you do, and the difficulty of seeing things from others' points of view

Comment: Why would *blinkered* not suit, please?

Comment: Balanced, the norm, reasonable, traditional, right.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Regis suggestion, but I would suggest egocentric:
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/egocentric

Answer (score 0):

**[Solipsist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/solipsist)**

> (philosophy) the extreme form of scepticism which denies the
>   possibility of any knowledge other than of one's own existence